Is it possible to stop VS Code from opening new instances of Python for every Jupyter notebook?
I am new to VS Code, and am writing Python in a set of Jupyter notebooks. Activity Monitor shows that VS Code opens new copies (instances? I am unsure of the correct terminology) of Python for every notebook, which is very RAM-intensive. I would really like the notebooks all to share the same copy of Python.
All the notebooks are running in the same conda environment, and I have selected the same kernel for each notebook. I've just moved to VS Code from running Jupyter notebooks in-browser, and this has never been an issue for me before, so I'm not sure if I've set something up wrong.
Is this behavior innate to VS Code? Can I change it?
